# How to add a listener to dynamically created RadioButtons?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I have a `ListView` of questions. In each row there is a question and a `RadioGroup` with possibile answers. Not all the questions have the same number of answers, so I add the `RadioButtons` dynamically in my custom `ListAdapter`. My question is how to add Listener to these dynamically created `RadioButtons`. My code:

```
RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.question);
        rg.removeAllViews();
        for (String qA : question.answers) {
            RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(getContext());
            rb.setText(qA.toString());
            rg.addView(rb);

        }

        rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                switch(checkedId) {
                    //WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE?
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: You want to identify which dynamically added RadioButton's state has been changed. Right?

Comment: @user370305 yes, you are right.

Comment: Ok, in your for loop of radio button just set Id for each RadioButton. as per loop count. like `rb.setId(count);`.

Comment: Should I simply use setId(id) on the radiobutton inside the loop?

Comment: Also do you need to know the list item position along with `RadioButton` or just `RadioButton` ?

Comment: I would like to know list item position along with RadioButton

Comment: Most probably like, `rg.setId(position); // list item position of getView()` and `rb.setId(count); // for loop count ..` now in  `onCheckedChanged` `group.getId()` returns list item position and `checkedId` returns radio button's position.

Answer (score 0):

Maby something like this:

```
@Override public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    RadioButton btn = (RadioButton)findViewById(checkedId);
}
```

and then something with the btn? :)

Answer (score 0):

To find the checked button

```
View checkedButton = rg.findViewById(checkedId);
```

To find the index of checked button

```
int checkedIndex = rg.indexOfChild(checkedButton);
```

Before doing the above you have to set id to the buttons like mentioned in the comments `rb.setId(count)`. Count has to be unique for each button within a group.

Answer (score 0):

1 first create global variable of **CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener** in your adapter for example private CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener **listener**

2 second you have to attach listener variable with your radio button at the time of creating the radio button.

3 third when you bind the data or value with your ui you have to call this method

```
listener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged ( CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked ) 
{

            }
        };
```